# DFSR not replicating

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

I have a replication group with two 2k8r2 servers as partners in a master<->master replication (so, both sides are always in sync and can update each other). This group is replicating two folders both used by IIS to share files. I have a webapp that dynamically generates output files and these servers are load balanced, so I need to have the output in both folders in basically real-time.

Now, it seems like replication hasn't worked since the initial replication with no indication of why. Event logs have no activity since the day it was set up about a week ago.

Output of `dfsrdiag replicationstate /member:server2`:

```
C:\Users\fnc>dfsrdiag replicationstate /member:server2 /v
[INFO] Computer Name: server2
[INFO] Computer DNS: server2.domain
[INFO] Domain Name: domain
[INFO] Domain DNS: domain.domain
[INFO] Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
[INFO] Connected to WMI services on computer: server.domain
[INFO] Issuing query: SELECT * FROM DfsrConnectionInfo
[INFO] Issuing query: SELECT * FROM DfsrIdUpdateInfo
[ERROR] Failed to execute WMI query

[INFO] Execution Time: 0 seconds
Operation Failed
```

Server 1 returns the same error.

Output of `dfsrdiag backlog /RGName:NameOfFolder /RFName:"Outputs" /SMem:server1 /RMem:server2`:

```
Member <server2> Backlog File Count: 32558
Backlog File Names (first 100 files)

Operation Succeeded
```

I don't understand what's going on. I have another pair of servers with DFSR replication serving our corporate file shares just fine, so this is puzzling.

Comment: Without looking at debug logs its hard to say what's happening. Given that the backlog command worked it seems like the root\microsoftdfs namespace is up. Not much else can be said with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I cloned the VMs resulting in a duplicate volume ID. After rebuilding DFSR on both partners and changing the volume ID of one of the servers, replication is now again working.

I also had an issue with a stale namespace which required a registry key to be deleted to fix.